# PostgreSQL service stops working

Tags: .net, database, wcf, web-services, postgresql

The problem I have is that my instance of PostgreSQL stops working often sometime after my application is running. By restarting PostgreSQL windows service I am able to get it working again, though I need to know what is making my postgres instance to stop working.

By looking at postgres log, I am getting this error (among others):

```
"FATAL:  could not reattach to shared memory (key=348, addr=01E70000): 487
2012-04-25 11:05:24 PDT WARNING:  worker took too long to start; cancelled"
```

This is the scenario I am working on. I am working with a WCF service that makes some processing on a PostgreSQL (8.3) database. There are 2 'client' machines consuming this web service every 10 seconds.

From the client application I am initializing the web service like

```
RemoteServiceClient service = new RemoteServiceClient();
```

On the web service side, on every initialization I make a new instance of the postgres connection. Here I am not opening the connection, only initializing:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    NpgsqlConnection connection = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor for remote service
    /// </summary>
    public Service()
    {
        connection = new NpgsqlConnection(Utils.DBConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Inside the functions of my web service, I open & close connections as needed, this way I don't leave opened connections on the fly. By looking at common activity while machines are consuming the web service, I notice only about 3-4 connections (IDLE when no DB activity is occurring). I checked postgres default settings and "max_connections" is set to 100.

I am really having a hard time with this problem, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I advise you to ask in the postgresql forum: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/

Comment: You should upgrade as soon as possible. 8.3 will be de-supported beginning of next year. And 9.x is much better on Windows

Answer (score 3):

There is a [bugfix in version 8.3.8](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/release-8-3-8.html) (Release Date: 2009-09-09) for this problem:

> Fix Windows shared-memory allocation code (Tsutomu Yamada, Magnus)
>
> This bug led to the often-reported "could not reattach to shared
>   memory" error message.

Check your version using `SELECT version();`